# "AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'basicConfig'"

Tags: python

I am learning logging

```
In [11]: !cat  program/codes/debug/logging.py                                                                                                         
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime) -%(levelname)s - %(message)s")
logging.debug('Start of program')

def factorial(n):
    logging.debug("Start of factorial(%s%%)" %(n))
    total = 1
    for i in range(n+1):
        total *= i
        logging.debug(f"i is {str(i)}, total is {str(total)}")
    logging.debug("End of factorial(%s%%)" %(n))
    return total

print(factorail(5))
logging.debug("End of program.")
```

It report unexpected error, when run it:

```
In [12]: !python program/codes/debug/logging.py                                                                                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program/codes/debug/logging.py", line 1, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/Users/gaowei/Desktop/Pubrepo/program/codes/debug/logging.py", line 2, in <module>
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime) -%(levelname)s - %(message)s")
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'basicConfig'
```

"AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'basicConfig'",

but it is

```
In [13]: logging.basicConfig                                                                                                                          
Out[13]: <function logging.basicConfig(**kwargs)>
```

Comment: You've called your file `logging.py`. Rename it, you're shadowing the module.

Comment: ty, please transmit the short comment to answer. @roganjosh

Comment: At best it's a dupe, I've voted to close as a typo. There's maybe 4 or 5 of these questions I see a day. Hence why I have about a ~30s response time, enough time to ensure I was correct in my guess once opening the question :)